# How to disable the datagridview rowvalidating event when using the same form to view/edit in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, datagridview

I'm trying to disable the datagridview rowvalidating event when using the same form to view/edit in vb.net.

so I use one `FormTransaction` to do adding and viewing/editing

so an error appears when I click the button `BtnViewEdit`.

Is there something wrong with the code?.

Please Guide Me

Thanks

Code In FormMain

```vb
Public Class FormMain
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim list = New List(Of Product)() From {
            New Product With {
                .Codeproduct = "1000",
                .Qty = 20,
                .Qty_Stock = 50
            },
            New Product With {
                .Codeproduct = "2000",
                .Qty = 30,
                .Qty_Stock = 40
            }
        }
        Dim bindingList As New BindingList(Of Product)(CType(list, IList(Of Product)))
        Dim source = New BindingSource(bindingList, Nothing)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = source
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
        Dim frm = New FormTransaction
        frm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnViewEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnViewEdit.Click
        Dim Invno = DirectCast(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem, Product)

        If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then ' make sure user select at least 1 row
            Using frm = New FormTransaction(Invno)

                If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

                End If
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Product
    Public Property Codeproduct() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
    Public Property Qty_Stock() As Integer
End Class
```

Code In FormTransaction

```vb
Public Class FormTransaction
    Private list As New List(Of Product)() From {
        New Product With {
        .Codeproduct = "1000",
        .Qty = 20,
        .Qty_Stock = 0
        },
        New Product With {
        .Codeproduct = "2000",
        .Qty = 30,
        .Qty_Stock = 40
        }
    }
    Private listnew As New List(Of Product)()

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim bindingList As New BindingList(Of Product)(CType(listnew, IList(Of Product)))
        Dim source = New BindingSource(bindingList, Nothing)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = source
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(Invno As Product)
        Me.New
        DataGridView1.DataSource = list
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowValidating
        Dim transferredQTY As Integer
        Dim onHandQTY As Integer

        With DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            Try
                transferredQTY = Convert.ToInt32(.Cells("Qty").Value)
            Catch ex As Exception
                transferredQTY = 0
            End Try
            Try
                onHandQTY = Convert.ToInt32(.Cells("Qty_Stock").Value)
            Catch ex As Exception
                onHandQTY = 0
            End Try
            If transferredQTY > onHandQTY Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please check don't Have sufficient quantity Stock" & "Only have Stock " & onHandQTY & " Pcs", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If

        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I use Button `ADD` Then the FormTransaction appears
with an empty dataGridView so here I input the outbound transaction and I use the rowvalidating event to control if `Qty` greater than  `Qty_Stock`

| CodeProduct | Qty | Qty_Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

If I use Button `VIEW/EDIT` Then the FormTransaction appears
But an error appears because it reads for Codeproduct `1000` don't have  `Qty_Stock` .So here's how I can disable rowvalidating events when the form is only used as a view/edit

| CodeProduct | Qty | Qty_Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 20 | 0 |
| 2000 | 30 | 40 |

[image: Errror When Click Btn BtnViewEdit 1]

[image: Errror When Click Btn BtnViewEdit 2]

Comment: You don't disable an event. You can choose whether to handle it or not and, if you do, you can choose whether to act on it or not in the event handler.

Comment: Don't post pictures of error messages. They are text so post the text, formatted appropriately. I'm on a phone and images are hard to read and you can copy text from them.

Comment: As for your issue, you need to debug your code, not just read it. Set a breakpoint and step through the code and examine the state. If you don't know how to debug them stop what you're doing and learn now. If you still need help, you have to tell us what you found.

Comment: [Tutorial: Learn to debug Visual Basic code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-debugger).

Comment: @jmcilhinney , The problem here I use the same form where at the time `ADD` then the enable event and at the time `view/edit` then disable event

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `Don't post pictures of error messages. They are text so post the text, formatted appropriately. I'm on a phone and images are hard to read and you can copy text from them. ` I have added an explanation with the table so that it can be understood

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `As for your issue, you need to debug your code, not just read it. Set a breakpoint and step through the code and examine the state. If you don't know how to debug them stop what you're doing and learn now. If you still need help, you have to tell us what you found` I have debugged only here how can I disable the event in the same form

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes , Thank you for your reply.  I have debugged only here how can I disable the event in the same form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the form differently in `BtnAdd` and `BtnViewEdit`. You can use this fact to set a Boolean variable (only showing the relevant parts):

```vb
Public Class FormTransaction
    ...

    Private showMessages As Boolean '<=========== is False when the Form is created.

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim bindingList As New BindingList(Of Product)(CType(listnew, IList(Of Product)))
        Dim source = New BindingSource(bindingList, Nothing)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = source
        showMessages = True '<========== Called from BtnAdd
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(Invno As Product)
        Me.New
        showMessages = False '<=========== Called from BtnViewEdit
        DataGridView1.DataSource = list
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowValidating
        Dim transferredQTY As Integer
        Dim onHandQTY As Integer

        With DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            ...

            If showMessages AndAlso transferredQTY > onHandQTY Then  '<===========
                MessageBox.Show("Please check don't Have sufficient quantity Stock" & "Only have Stock " & onHandQTY & " Pcs", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you your perfect answer. so if I want to enable event `showMessages = True` and and another button if I want disabled event `showMessages = False`

Comment: so code like this `Public Sub New()  InitializeComponent() showMessages = True` From button `BtnAdd` and `Public Sub New(Invno As Product)  Me.New showMessages = False` from button `BtnViewEdit`

Comment: Okay I got it the wrong way round. I corrected the code now.